# Why can we initialize inside a function and still use that value outside the function?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, stack, heap-memory

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int n;
    double d;
} some_thing;

void alloc_and_init_some_thing(some_thing** s, int n, double d) {
    some_thing si = { .n=n, .d=d };
    *s = malloc(sizeof(**s));
    memcpy(*s, &si, sizeof(**s));
}

void alloc_and_init_int(int **i) {
    int j = 21; 
    *i = malloc(sizeof(**i));
    memcpy(*i, &j, sizeof(**i));
}

int main() {
    some_thing *s;
    alloc_and_init_some_thing(&s, 41, 31);
    printf("s->n=%d s->d=%f\n", s->n, s->d);

    int *i; 
    alloc_and_init_int(&i);
    printf("*i=%d\n", *i);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm still learning C and the difference between the stack and the heap. When we declare and initialize the variable `si` in the function `alloc_and_init_some_thing`, doesn't this value exist on the stack? Hence it should get wiped out when the function finishes?

But I can see that that doesn't actually occur. Back in the main function, when we print `s->n`, we get the value `41`.

Similarly, when we print the value for `*i` in the main function, it prints `21`.

Why is that?

Comment: The code can be simplified if you let the allocation function return the pointer. Then you can remove some dereference operators (one * less).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `memcpy(*s, &si, sizeof(**s));` copies the the structure `si` on the stack into the heap allocated structure `s`, thus making it persist in memory as heap allocations can be accessed anywhere in the program. It's merely a pointer to an address in memory.

The same thing happens in the similar function.

Comment: This makes sense. I was confused. I misremembered what ```memcpy``` does. I kept thinking that ```memcpy(*s, &si, sizeof(**s));``` copied the address of ```si``` into the address of ```*s```. But it actually copies the valued stored at ```si``` into the location pointed at by ```*s```. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the lifetime of "si" and "j" are limited to their respective functions and not available after the return from those functions. However, their contents have been replicated via malloc/memcpy prior to the return of the functions and the pointers to the replicas are stored in variables "s" and "i", which are still alive at the time of printing (or using) those replicas.